# Accessing ViewModel function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout to make a commentfield and I have changed from using several viewmodels to one parent viewmodel because I got some conflicts when using foreach. My new problem is to run a function from my parent ViewModel. My Comment() function works but i'm having problems calling commentSection() from within the javascript.

I want to call a getNewEntries from the function commentSection. I thought the way to do this would be to call my Viewmodel(vm) with vm.cSection.getNewEntries but console says its not a function. So my question is, how can I call this function getNewEntries through vm?

Here's how it looks:

```
    function Comment() {
    var self = this;

    self.nickname = ko.observable();
    self.newMsg = ko.observable("");

    self.sendEntry = function() {

        if (self.newMsg() !== "" && self.nickname() !== "") {

            $.post(writeUrl, "entry=" + ko.toJSON(self));
            self.newMsg("");
        }
    };
}
function commentSection() {
    var self = this;
    self.timestamp = 0;
    self.comments = ko.observableArray();
    self.editable = ko.observable(false);

    self.deleteComment = function() {
        vm.cSection.comments.remove(self);
    };

    self.editComment = function() {
        self.editable(!self.editable());
    };
    self.getNewEntries = function() {
        $.getJSON(readUrl, "timestamp=" + self.timestamp, function(comments) {
            for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
                var entry = comments[i];
                if (entry.timestamp > self.timestamp) {
                    self.timestamp = entry.timestamp;
                }
                self.comments.unshift(entry);
            }
            self.getNewEntries();
        });

    };

}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.cSection = ko.observable(new commentSection());
    self.comments = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedComment = ko.observable(new Comment());

    //self.cSection.getNewEntries();
}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.cSection.getNewEntries();
```

});

Tell me if my question is unclear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cSection` is an observable, you have to unwrap it to get the `commentSection` instance:

```
vm.cSection().getNewEntries();
```

Same thing in `deleteComment` function:

```
self.deleteComment = function() {
    vm.cSection().comments.remove(self);
};
```

Comment: Ah so it was that simple. Rookie mistake! Thanks alot. :)